# How to search through a huge JSON file locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

I have a giant JSON file hosted locally (+170 000 lines) which I would like to search through in Javascript/Jquery.
For the moment, I simply tried this:

```
$.getJSON("recipeList.json", (json) => {
    console.log("It Works !"); 
});
```

which doesn't seem to be working : no console.log, only an error in the console saying

`[Violation] 'load' handler took 1142ms`

**Is there anyway I could make searches through this file, even though it is huge, and without taking too much time ?** 
 I also have the url to the file hosted online (https://s3.amazonaws.com/openrecipes/20170107-061401-recipeitems.json.gz), but it seems I can't connect to it (CORS error about no header allowing me).

Comment: its not error but warning, you need more wait. and it better to split the json

Answer (score 0):

That is a big file ~ 30 MB and 135 MB uncompressed.

I believe you will need Server-Side help for this.

Maybe you can download this file and then insert its data into the Database (MySQL for example)

And then create an API which you will call from the Client-Side to fetch data from DB by provided search term.